# Phonegap local links

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to phone gap and have been reading up on it for a while, however I have recently put an app into the build yet get errors. Everything works fine on the homepage, yet on another page something accessed the same way, will not be accessible in the same manner.
For example in my home page i have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

yet when I use the exact same piece of code on another page, it does not work.

The same goes for the links I am using.
on the index this works fine:

```
<a href="pages/select_level.html"><h2>Select Level</h2></a>
```

yet when I attempt to access any other page from this page in the same manner(including the index), i get a error

"There was a network erro.(file:///data/data/com.phonegap.www/hydra_app/pages/idex.html)"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a link error. Is the navigation working fine in the browser?

`There was a network erro.(file:///data/data/com.phonegap.www/hydra_app/pages/idex.html)`: it's pointing to `.../pages/index.html` while it may need to point to `.../index.html` (ie it's looking for `index.html` under the `pages` folder while it may be at the top level).